# htaccess - Force rewrite url to use subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have address `http://example.com/blog` which redirects to URL specified in application.
Now I need to 'force' this URL to use subdirectory `blog`, so when I go to `http://example.com/blog` it will be use `/blog` subdirectory.
How can I do this by `.htaccess` file?

Here is my dir structure:

```
+- blog/  
+-----index.php
+-----.htaccess
+- app/
+- assets/
+- resources/
+- cache/
+- .htaccess
+- index.php
```

Current **root** `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/sitemap.xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/en/sitemap.xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/ru/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /?module=toolkits&action=xmlsitemap [L]

RewriteRule !(\.(ico|cdr|js|xml|flv|css|gif|jpe?g|png|tif|swf|doc|xls|pdf|zip|rar|ttf|eot|htc|otf|csv|woff|woff2|svg|mp4|map|txt))$ index.php [L,NC]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        <Filesmatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|xml|js|css|swf|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|mp3|mp4|map)$">
                ExpiresActive on
                ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
        </Filesmatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On

#
#
#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point your [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive to a folder which will serve as a base for all your relative paths.

```
RewriteBase "/blog/"
```

Comment: So this should use subdirectory `blog` when someone reach `http://example.com/blog` ?

Comment: Yes. If you put the `RewriteBase` inside your `/blog/.htaccess` file all following requests will remain inside that subfolder when resolving relative paths.